# Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource, locale en_US running native docker image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, eclipselink, spring-native

**You can check out this repo to reproduce the error ourself: https://github.com/vanonnahenrik/demo-service**

I have a Spring Boot 3.0.4 app, running it with `spring-boot:run` works fine, but when I build the docker image with `mvn clean spring-boot:build-image -Pnative -DskipTests` (that works) and then running the image with `docker run --rm demo-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` it fails with this error:

```
2023-06-20T09:32:19.419Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.d.prodis.service.registry.Application  : Starting AOT-processed Application using Java 17.0.7 with PID 1 (/workspace/de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application started by cnb in /workspace)
2023-06-20T09:32:19.420Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.d.prodis.service.registry.Application  : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2023-06-20T09:32:19.465Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-20T09:32:19.468Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-20T09:32:19.468Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-06-20T09:32:19.476Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-20T09:32:19.476Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 56 ms
2023-06-20T09:32:19.495Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource, locale en_US
2023-06-20T09:32:19.495Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-20T09:32:19.497Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource, locale en_US
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:3.0.4]
        at de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource, locale en_US
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1280) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.ExceptionMessageGenerator.buildMessage(ExceptionMessageGenerator.java:71) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:233) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2150) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2126) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:4.0.1]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:4.0.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application:6.0.6]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

The file mentioned in the stacktrace ("org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource") exists in the eclipselink-4.0.1.jar which is a maven dependency, this is it's content:

```
 * Copyright (c) 1998, 2021 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0,
 * or the Eclipse Distribution License v. 1.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
 */

// Contributors:
//     Oracle - initial API and implementation from Oracle TopLink
package org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

/**
 * INTERNAL:
 * English ResourceBundle for EntityManagerSetupException messages.
 *
 * @author Tom Ware
 */
public final class EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource extends ListResourceBundle {
    static final Object[][] contents = {
                                           { "28001", "A ValidationException was thrown while trying to create session: [{0}]. " +
                                                   "The most likely causes of this issue are that your [{1}] file is not available on the classpath " +
                                                   "or it does not contain a session called: [{0}]." },
                                           { "28002", "EclipseLink is attempting to load a ServerSession named [{0}] from [{1}], and not getting a ServerSession." },
                                           { "28003", "EclipseLink has loaded Session [{0}] from [{1}] and it either does not have a server platform specified or specifies " +
                                                   "a server platform that does not use and external transaction controller.  Specify an appropriate server platform if you plan to use JTA." },
                                           { "28004", "Error in setup of EntityManager factory: JavaSECMPInitializer.initializeFromMain returned false." },
                                           { "28005", "An Exception was thrown in setup of EntityManager factory." },
                                           { "28006", "ClassNotFound: [{0}] specified in [{1}] property." },
                                           { "28007", "Failed to instantiate ServerPlatform of type [{0}] specified in [{1}] property." },
                                           { "28008", "Class: {0} was not found while processing annotations." },
                                           { "28009", "Attempted to redeploy a session named {0} without closing it." },
                                           { "28010", "PersistenceUnitInfo {0} has transactionType JTA, but does not have a jtaDataSource defined." },
                                           { "28011", "The session, [{0}], built for a persistence unit was not available at the time it was deployed.  This means that somehow the session was removed from the container in the middle of the deployment process." },
                                           { "28012", "Value [{0}] is of incorrect type for property [{2}], value type should be [{1}]." },
                                           { "28013", "Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [{0}] in invalid state [{1}]." },
                                           { "28014", "Exception was thrown while processing property [{0}] with value [{1}]." },
                                           { "28015", "Failed to instantiate SessionLog of type [{0}] specified in [{1}] property." },
                                           { "28016", "The persistence unit with name [{0}] does not exist." },
                                           { "28017", "Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [{0}] in invalid state [{1}]." },
                                           { "28018", "Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [{0}] failed." },
                                           { "28019", "Deployment of PersistenceUnit [{0}] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit." },
                                           { "28020", "The session with name [{0}] loaded from [{1}] is [{2}], it however must be ServerSession." },
                                           { "28021", "PersistenceUnit [{0}] attempts to load a session from [{1}] without providing a session name.  A session name should be provided by defining the eclipselink.session-name property." },
                                           { "28022", "Value [true] for the property [eclipselink.weaving] is incorrect when global instrumentation is null, value should either be null, false, or static." },
                                           { "28023", "The method invocation of the method [{0}] on the object [{1}], of class [{2}], triggered an exception." },
                                           { "28024", "Cannot reflectively access the method [{0}] for object [{1}], of class [{2}]." },
                                           { "28025", "The persistence unit with name [{0}] has returned a [null] temporary classLoader - weaving has been disabled for this session.  You may use static weaving is an optional workaround." },
                                           { "28026", "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.PersistenceProvider does not support container deployment (createContainerEntityManagerFactory).  Use org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider instead." },
                                           { "28027", "An attempt has been made to use PersistenceUnit [{0}], but no bundle is available that defines that persistence unit." },
                                           { "28028", "Failed to instantiate class instance [{0}] for persistence unit property [{1}], ensure constructor is defined correctly." },
                                           { "28029", "PersistenceUnit [{0}] tries both to use sessions.xml (specifies eclipselink.sessions-xml property) and to be a composite (specifies eclipselink.composite-unit property with value true). These modes are incompatible." },
                                           { "28030", "PersistenceUnit [{0}] specifies eclipselink.composite-unit.member property with value true. That means it cannot be used standalone, but only as a composite member." },
                                           { "28031", "Missing the required property [{0}]." },
                                           { "28032", "Failed to create temporary classloader with doPrivileged." }
   };

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public EntityManagerSetupExceptionResource() {
        // for reflection
    }

    /**
     * Return the lookup table.
     */
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>demo.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-service</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <eclipselink.version>4.0.1</eclipselink.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.78</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>cfg/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>logback-spring.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>cfg/**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>systemd/**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

So what exactly am I missing here?
My guess is that this is a problem with spring, not eclipselink.

Comment: Hi! have you figured this out? I encountered the same error